# Docker service running but not binding to host port gives 503 Service Unavailable

Tags: docker

Docker service should bind to port 2007.

```
root@docker:~# docker service ls | grep 2007
hn7ljux4l6ib   access_agency_overview-feature        replicated   1/1        docker-repo.com/access_agency_overview:feature       *:2007->80/tcp
```

Also check with `docker inspect` to see if port was published or not. Looking great

```
root@docker:~# docker service inspect hn7ljux4l6ib | grep Port
                "Ports": [
                        "TargetPort": 80,
                        "PublishedPort": 2007,
                "Ports": [
                        "TargetPort": 80,
                        "PublishedPort": 2007,
            "Ports": [
                    "TargetPort": 80,
                    "PublishedPort": 2007,
```

Also looking great with `docker logs`

```
root@docker:~# docker logs 047166727d33
/docker-entrypoint.sh: /docker-entrypoint.d/ is not empty, will attempt to perform configuration
/docker-entrypoint.sh: Looking for shell scripts in /docker-entrypoint.d/
/docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching /docker-entrypoint.d/10-listen-on-ipv6-by-default.sh
10-listen-on-ipv6-by-default.sh: Getting the checksum of /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
10-listen-on-ipv6-by-default.sh: Enabled listen on IPv6 in /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
/docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching /docker-entrypoint.d/20-envsubst-on-templates.sh
/docker-entrypoint.sh: Configuration complete; ready for start up
```

but `netstat -tulnp | grep 2007` gives no output.

As well as curl to localhost

```
root@docker:~# curl http://localhost:2007
curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 2007: Connection refused
```

ps. 2007 allowed on firewall

Edited for adding result from `docker ps`

```
047166727d33   docker-repo.com/access_agency_overview:feature       "/docker-entrypoint.…"   24 minutes ago      Up 24 minutes      80/tcp                   access_agency_overview-feature.1.ucti38zri157sc8014y0f3cjq
```

Comment: Can you post the result of a "docker ps" command?

Comment: Thanks @StephanMøller I've added result from docker ps.

Comment: Which network model do you use in docker? If you use host-network, then your container is listening on port 80 on localhost. What does curl http://localhost:80 give you?

Comment: Another test is to dive into the container using "docker exec -it [containername] -bash" and then run a curl or wget from inside the container, to ensure that the localhost:80 works inside the container.

Comment: If port mapping was correct setup, you would se both ports shown in the docker ps result. As you only see port 80 I suspect that either you run the host network model OR the bridge network model that allows for other containers to reach it but not the host. I am looking forward to hear the test results from the other suggestions I had :)

Comment: Bth any updates?

Comment: @StephanMøller sorry for late reply. I didn't investigate more for the cause since restart docker daemon solve the issue. But thanks for your kindness, it's really helpful. I'll use your suggestion as a guideline :)